# Find balance of an address/contract at a given block / date

Tags: node, rpc, api, archive-node

Do we have any api mechanism to find the balance for an address/contract for a given blockheight or till a given date.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HTTP-RPC interface on your local node.

`http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/{BLOCK}/context/contracts/{ADDRESS}/balance`

On a default node, this is only good for the previous 5 cycles. If you want balances older than that, you need to use an `archive` node.

Other options are to use the API provided by most block explorers like tzstats.com and tzkt.io which have account history back to block 1.